# is it possible to scp any file type in all subdirectories starting from root?

Tags: 14.04, copy, scp

I am trying to copy any files with the extension `.pf` to another box. is it possible to do this and keep the file path structure too?

I tried

```
scp -rp /*.pf user@10.10.10.10:CP
```

but it fails with `*.pf: No such file or directory`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `rsync` instead of `scp` because it offers more options:

```
rsync -avm --include="*/" --include="*.pf" --exclude="*" / user@10.10.10.10:CP/
```

Unfortunately, it is a bit complicated when it comes to `rsync`'s `include` and 
`exclude` parameters. Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11111562/5830574) over on Stack Overflow
for details.

They say (for `*.sh` files instead of `*.pf` files):

> So if we only want `*.sh` files we have to exclude all 
>   files `--exclude="*"`, include all directories `--include="*/"` 
>   and include all `*.sh` files `--include="*.sh"`.

To get a *preview* first, add the `-n` switch to the call. This will 
instruct `rsync` to only *tell* what it would do whithout actually
doing it:

```
rsync -avm -n --include … 
           ^^
```

Further reference:

- [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=763833&p=8546521#post8546521)